# MPU6050 and STM32F4 data transmission issue

Tags: stm32, mpu6050

I am using a STM32F446 with a MPU6050, I am using I2C communication for this application, the problem is that it only shows me one value and does not update, I mean, if the value in the serial monitor is 1, 1, 1 then it only shows that one every single time and it does not show another one even if I disconnect and connect the MPU to the STM32. I also tried to debug line by line in order to find the error but it just seems that the program gets stuck in the very first data transmit line of the MPU_Init function.

```
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MPU_ADDRESS 0xD0

I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1 = {0};
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2 = {0};

void GPIO_Init(void);
void Error_Handler(void);
void Clock_Config(void);
void UART2_Init(void);
void I2C1_Init(void);
void MPU_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
uint8_t bufOut[32], bufIn[12], buflen;
HAL_Init();
Clock_Config();
GPIO_Init();
UART2_Init();
I2C1_Init();
MPU_Init();
while(1)
{
    bufOut[0] = 0x3B;
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, MPU_ADDRESS, bufOut, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, MPU_ADDRESS, bufIn, 12, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    int16_t acc_x_raw = ((uint16_t)bufIn[0] << 8) | bufIn[1];
    int16_t acc_y_raw = ((uint16_t)bufIn[2] << 8) | bufIn[3];
    int16_t acc_z_raw = ((uint16_t)bufIn[4] << 8) | bufIn[5];

    buflen = sprintf((char *)bufOut, "Accel: %i %i %i\r\n", acc_x_raw, acc_y_raw, acc_z_raw);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, bufOut, buflen, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    HAL_Delay(100);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);
}
return 0;
}

void MPU_Init(void)
{
uint8_t buffer[2];

buffer[0] = 0x6B;
buffer[1] = 0x80;
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, MPU_ADDRESS, buffer, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
HAL_Delay(10);

buffer[0] = 0x6B;
buffer[1] = 0x00;
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, MPU_ADDRESS, buffer, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
HAL_Delay(10);

buffer[0] = 0x6B;
buffer[1] = 0x00;
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, MPU_ADDRESS, buffer, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
HAL_Delay(10);

buffer[0] = 0x6C;
buffer[1] = ~(0x3F);
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, MPU_ADDRESS, buffer, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
HAL_Delay(10);

buffer[0] = 0x1A;
buffer[1] = 0x00;
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, MPU_ADDRESS, buffer, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
HAL_Delay(10);

buffer[0] = 0x1B;
buffer[1] = 0x00;
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, MPU_ADDRESS, buffer, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
HAL_Delay(10);

buffer[0] = 0x1C;
buffer[1] = 0x00;
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, MPU_ADDRESS, buffer, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
HAL_Delay(10);
}

void UART2_Init(void)
{
/* Habilitar señales de reloj */
__HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

/* Configuración de bajo nivel */
GPIO_InitTypeDef uart_pins = {0};
uart_pins.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
uart_pins.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
uart_pins.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART2;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &uart_pins);

/* Habilitar interrupción */

/* Configuración de alto nivel */
huart2.Instance = USART2;
huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX;
if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
    Error_Handler();
}

void I2C1_Init(void)
{
/* Habilitar el reloj del periférico */
__HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

/* Configuración de Bajo nivel */
GPIO_InitTypeDef i2c_pins = {0};
i2c_pins.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7;
i2c_pins.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
i2c_pins.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C1;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &i2c_pins);

/* Habilitar Interrupciones */

/* Configuración de alto nivel */
hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
//hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
    Error_Handler();
}

void Clock_Config(void)
{
RCC_OscInitTypeDef osc_init = {0};
osc_init.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
osc_init.HSEState = RCC_HSE_BYPASS;
osc_init.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
osc_init.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
osc_init.PLL.PLLM = 4;
osc_init.PLL.PLLN = 180;
osc_init.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
osc_init.PLL.PLLQ = 2;
osc_init.PLL.PLLR = 2;

if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&osc_init) != HAL_OK)
    Error_Handler();

RCC_ClkInitTypeDef clock_init = {0};
clock_init.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
clock_init.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK |
        RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
clock_init.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
clock_init.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
clock_init.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&clock_init, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
    Error_Handler();
}

void Error_Handler(void)
{
while(1)
{
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);
    HAL_Delay(100);
}
}

void GPIO_Init(void)
{
__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

GPIO_InitTypeDef led_pin = {0};
led_pin.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
led_pin.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &led_pin);
}

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
HAL_IncTick();
HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you configuring the MPU6050 with continuous measuring mode? The sensor may be working in single ADC conversion mode. This won't update the data registers. And another thing is why are you using `HAL_MAX_DELAY` for I2C timeout value? This value blocks the CPU until timeout value passed.